# Explicit elementary primitive (integral) of $x / \sqrt{P(x)}$ and Galois group of $P$

Tags: integration, galois-theory, indefinite-integrals, elementary-functions

I am reading some stuff on Risch's algorithm [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithme_de_Risch#Exemple) (Wikipedia in French), about finding explicitly some primitive of functions in terms of "elementary functions" (composition of polynomials, log, exp, trigonometric functions, ...).

They mention that
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{4}+10x^{2}-96x-71}}$$
has an explicit primitive, of the form $-1/8 \cdot \log(P(x) \sqrt{x^{4}+10x^{2}-96x-71} - Q(x))$ for some $P, Q \in \mathbb Z[x]$.
On the other hand, they say that the integral of
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{4}+10x^{2}-96x-72}}$$
cannot be expressed using elementary functions.

They claim that this is because the Galois group of (the splitting field of) the polynomial $x^{4}+10x^{2}-96x-72$ is $S_4$ (24 elements) while the one of $x^{4}+10x^{2}-96x-71$ is $D_4$ (8 elements).
I don't understand how this can influence Risch's algorithm. Both groups are solvable, so I'm not sure what the problem really is.

Can anyone explain the relation between the Galois groups of $P$ and the expression of $\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{P(x)}} dx$ via elementary functions? I did not find anything in the book "Bronstein, Symbolic Integration I" which does cover Risch's algorithm and a bit of differential Galois theory.

Comment: There may be something in Alf van der Poorten and Xuan Chuong Tran, Quasi-elliptic integrals and periodic continued fractions, Monatshefte Math 131 (2000) 155-169. They study integrals of the shape $$\int{f(x)\,dx\over\sqrt{D(x)}}=\log(p(x)+q(x)\sqrt{D(x)})$$ with $f$ of degree $g$, and $D$ of degree $2g+2$.

Comment: Thanks. I think the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403228.pdf, especially thm 1 and remark below, can be relevant. The answer is given in Corollary 3. "If a monic polynomial D of even degree is irreducible and with Galois group the full symmetric group then D is not exceptional" (see the paper for definition of 'exceptional').